# Efeitos Javascript/Jquery não funcionando na hora de criar a tabela no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia a todos,

Estou com um problema na hora de exibir uma tabela no html, eu quero acrescentar um efeito enquanto ela vai apresentando por exemplo estou usando

> $("#delayed").click(function(){
>               $("tr").delay(1000).show("slow");
>           })

Só que a hora que exibe a tabela ela vai rapido e n vem com o efeito segue abaixo o código em HTML, JS e CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("p").delay(200).hide("slow");
        })
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("p").delay(200).show("slow");
        })
        $("#delayed").click(function(){
            $("tr").delay(1000).show("slow");
        })
        $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", function(dado){
            var i;
            out = "<table border='0'>";
            for(i = 0; i < dado.length; i++){
                out+= "<tr id='delayed'><td>"+dado[i].id+"</td>";
                out+= "<td>"+dado[i].name+"</td>";
                out+= "<td>"+dado[i].email+"</td></tr>";
            }
            out += "</table>"
            document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = out;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
h1{
    color: #fd9500;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.button{
    border: none;
    color: #daf5ff;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-color: #0022ff;
}
.button span{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
}
.button span:after{
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8578f7;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fd9500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="functionJS.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Treinamento Front-End</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="style" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Lista de Pessoas</h1>
    <button class="button"><span>Get Back Requests</span></button>
    <button class="button" id="hide"><span>Hide Request</span></button>
    <button class="button" id="show"><span>Show Requests</span></button>
    <p  id="teste"></p>
</header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cara sua semântica Html está errada, nunca coloque script para carregar logo no início da página, coloque sempre depois dos Css, isto gera uma demora maior no carregamento da página.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var teste = $("#teste").hide();
          $("#hide").click(function(){
              $("p").delay(200).hide("slow");
          })
          $("#show").click(function(){
              $("p").delay(200).show("slow");
          })
          $("#get").click(function(){
              $("p").delay(1000).show("slow");
          })
          $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", function(dado){
              var i;
              out = "<table border='0'>";
              for(i = 0; i < dado.length; i++){
                  out+= "<tr class='a'><td>"+dado[i].id+"</td>";
                  out+= "<td>"+dado[i].name+"</td>";
                  out+= "<td>"+dado[i].email+"</td></tr>";
              }
              out += "</table>"
              document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = out;
          });
  });
```

```css
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  h1{
   color: #fd9500;
  }
  header{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .button{
   border: none;
   color: #daf5ff;
   padding: 15px 32px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 4px 2px;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   background-color: #0022ff;
  }
  .button span{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   transition: 1s;
  }
  .button span:after{
   content: '\00bb';
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
   transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .button:hover span{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   transition: 1s;
   box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
   padding-right: 25px;
  }
  .button:hover span:after {
   opacity: 1;
   right: 0;
  }
  table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
  }

  th, td{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #8578f7;
   padding: 8px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fd9500;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="style" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<header>
     <h1>Lista de Pessoas</h1>
     <button class="button" id="get"><span>Get Back Requests</span></button>
     <button class="button" id="hide"><span>Hide Request</span></button>
     <button class="button" id="show"><span>Show Requests</span></button>
     <p id="teste"></p>
 </header>
```

> Esta função não executa pq no HTML ela não achou nenhum id **delayed**

```
    $("#delayed").click(function(){
        $("tr").delay(1000).show("slow");
    })
```

Comment: Desculpa, eu coloquei errado essa parte sem querer mas mesmo colocando na parte o id ele n funciona para fazer

Comment: Faz assim que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro problema que verifico é a repetição do `id='delayed'`. Pode remover porque me parece desnecessário, ficando apenas:

```
...
out+= "<tr><td>"+dado[i].id+"</td>";
...
```

Outro problema são esses eventos dentro de outro evento:

```
$("button").click(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("p").delay(200).hide("slow");
        })
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("p").delay(200).show("slow");
        })
        $("#delayed").click(function(){
            $("tr").delay(1000).show("slow");
        })
```

Não precisa fazer isso, coloque os eventos separados, e remova o `$("#delayed").click(`, ficando apenas:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
   $("p").delay(200).hide("slow");
})
$("#show").click(function(){
   $("p").delay(200).show("slow");
})
```

Outra coisa é o `<p id="teste">` que deveria iniciar oculto com:

```
#teste{
   display: none;
}
```

Altere também o seletor do evento que irá chamar o Ajax, para pegar o click apenas do primeiro `button`:

```
$("button:eq(0)").click(function(){...
```

E após o retorno do Ajax, dispare um click na `div #show` para mostrar o resultado com efeito:

```
$("#show").click();
```

O código todo ficaria assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hide").click(function(){
         $("p").delay(200).hide("slow");
      })
      $("#show").click(function(){
         $("p").delay(200).show("slow");
      })
    $("button:eq(0)").click(function(){
        $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", function(dado){
            var i;
            out = "<table border='0'>";
            for(i = 0; i < dado.length; i++){
                out+= "<tr><td>"+dado[i].id+"</td>";
                out+= "<td>"+dado[i].name+"</td>";
                out+= "<td>"+dado[i].email+"</td></tr>";
            }
            out += "</table>"
            document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = out;
            $("#show").click();
        });
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
h1{
    color: #fd9500;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.button{
    border: none;
    color: #daf5ff;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-color: #0022ff;
}
.button span{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
}
.button span:after{
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8578f7;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fd9500;
}

#teste{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h1>Lista de Pessoas</h1>
    <button class="button"><span>Get Back Requests</span></button>
    <button class="button" id="hide"><span>Hide Request</span></button>
    <button class="button" id="show"><span>Show Requests</span></button>
    <p id="teste"></p>
</header>
```